# Naming gitRepo mount path in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

When using a gitRepo volume in Kubernetes, the repo is cloned into the mountPath directory.  For the following pod specification, for example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: server
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /usr/share/docroot
      name: docroot-volume
  volumes:
  - name: docroot-volume
    gitRepo:
      repository: "git@somewhere:me/my-git-repository.git"
```

The directory appears in the container at /usr/share/docroot/my-git-repository.  This means my container needs to know my repository name.  I don't want my container knowing anything about the repository name.  It should just know there is a "docroot", however initialized.  The only place the git repository name should appear is in the pod specification.

Is there anyway in Kubernetes to specify the full internal path to a git repo volume mount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no native way to do this, but I filed an [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15421) for you.

[Under the hood](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/volume/git_repo/git_repo.go#L141) kuberetes is just doing a `git clone $source` over an emptyDir volume, but since the source is passed as a single argument there is no way to specify the destination name.

```
Fri, 09 Oct 2015 18:35:01 -0700 Fri, 09 Oct 2015 18:49:52 -0700 90  {kubelet stclair-minion-nwpu}       FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to exec 'git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.git k8s': Cloning into 'kubernetes.git k8s'...
error: The requested URL returned error: 400 while accessing https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.git k8s/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
: exit status 128
```

In the meantime, I can think of 2 options to avoid the dependency on the repository name:

1. Supply the repository name as an [environment variable](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/configuring-containers.html#environment-variables-and-variable-expansion), which you can then use from your container
2. Modify your [containers command](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/configuring-containers.html#launching-a-container-using-a-configuration-file) to move the repository to the desired location before continuing

Comment: Thanks.  I prefer the second method, since that keeps the image ignorant of how the data is inserted.  It does mean I have to find out and copy the container's existing command to my own command.  It would be handy to have a 'pod initializer' container that would run once between pod initialization and the pod's regular containers to look after all the required initialization (e.g. permission fixups etc.).  Actually, an array of initializers would be even better.

Comment: I believe what you're asking for is the "pre-start hook", described [here](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/container-environment.html#hook-details). Unfortunately, hooks are a work in progress and the pre-start hook is not yet implemented.